# Why does key disappear from subclassed dict when iterating over `dict_keys`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key

I ran across strange behavior in Python 3.6.3 when iterating over the keys of an object subclassed from `dict`. I already understand that the behavior of `dict.keys()` changed from Python 2 to Python 3 to return a `dict_keys` object so the shallow copy behavior seen is understandable. What I don't understand is why one of the elements in `dict_keys` can be found with an explicit search but doesn't appear when iterating over the `dict_keys` object.

Here's the MWE:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function

class chemdist(dict):
    def normalize_names(self, force_static=False):

        if force_static:
            raw_chems = tuple(self.keys())
        else:
            raw_chems = self.keys()

        print("raw_chems is " + repr(raw_chems))

        if 'Ar' in raw_chems:
            print("Found Argon!")

        for old_chem in raw_chems:
            print("Checking {:s}".format(old_chem))
            if old_chem.startswith('_'):
                new_chem = old_chem
            else:
                new_chem = '_' + old_chem

            if old_chem != new_chem:
                curr_keys = self.keys()
                if new_chem in curr_keys:
                    self[new_chem] += self[old_chem]
                else:
                    self[new_chem] = self[old_chem]

                del self[old_chem]

def main():
    h_dryair = {
        'N2' : 78.084,
        'O2' : 20.947,
        'Ar' :  0.934,
        'CO2' : 0.0350
    }

    print("Test 1: Not static")
    cd_dryair = chemdist(h_dryair)

    print("  Unnormalized:")
    print(cd_dryair)

    print("\n  Normalizing:")
    cd_dryair.normalize_names()

    print("\n  Normalized:")
    print(cd_dryair)

    print("\n\nTest 2: Static")
    cd_dryair = chemdist(h_dryair)

    print("  Unnormalized:")
    print(cd_dryair)

    print("\n  Normalizing:")
    cd_dryair.normalize_names(force_static=True)

    print("\n  Normalized:")
    print(cd_dryair)

main()
```

And here are the results:

```
Test 1: Not static
  Unnormalized:
{'N2': 78.084, 'O2': 20.947, 'Ar': 0.934, 'CO2': 0.035}

  Normalizing:
raw_chems is dict_keys(['N2', 'O2', 'Ar', 'CO2'])
Found Argon!
Checking N2
Checking O2
Checking CO2
Checking _N2
Checking _O2
Checking _CO2

  Normalized:
{'Ar': 0.934, '_N2': 78.084, '_O2': 20.947, '_CO2': 0.035}


Test 2: Not static
  Unnormalized:
{'N2': 78.084, 'O2': 20.947, 'Ar': 0.934, 'CO2': 0.035}

  Normalizing:
raw_chems is ('N2', 'O2', 'Ar', 'CO2')
Found Argon!
Checking N2
Checking O2
Checking Ar
Checking CO2

  Normalized:
{'_N2': 78.084, '_O2': 20.947, '_Ar': 0.934, '_CO2': 0.035}
```

In Test 1, the element `'Ar'` is found by explicitly searching for it in `raw_chems`. However when iterating over `raw_chems`, the element `'Ar'` never appears (`"Checking Ar"` never appears).

In Test 2, `raw_chems` is cast to a tuple and `"Checking Ar"` appears as expected.

Also, compare the final normalized object contents: in Test 1, the `'Ar'` key has not been replaced with `'_Ar'` as it has in Test 2. `'Ar'` is the only key in Test 1 that hasn't been prefixed with an underscore.

I have two guesses at the cause of this problem: `dict_keys` has some *obvious-to-everyone-but-me* behavior or some weirdness is happening because I'm subclassing `dict`. Possibly a combination of the two.

And before someone gratuitously tries to change the question I'm asking, the Big Picture problem I'm trying to solve is to rename the dict keys to a canonical form (`HH`, `H2`, and `molecular hydrogen` all represent the same thing). While that may be a more interesting issue for some to address, I'm asking about the disappearing key, so please focus on the *x* as stated instead of the *y* you imagine... :)

Answer (score 0):

In python 3 `dict.keys()` is a view on the actual keys and changes, if the dictionary keys changes. You must not change the keys of a dictionary if you iterate over the keys.

Answer (score 0):

`dict.keys()` under Python 3 returns a view into the dictionary's keys. When you change the dictionary's keys, you change the contents of `dict.keys()` as well. This can lead to an item being skipped, just as when you delete items while iterating over a list:

Assume you're about to process `O2`:

```
    N2
--> O2
    Ar
    CO2
```

You process it and remove `O2` and add `_O2`. In the process, `Ar` slides into the slot that contained `O2`.

```
    N2
--> Ar
    CO2
    _O2
```

Now you proceed to the next iteration of the loop, which advances the "current item" pointer to the next item:

```
    N2
    Ar
--> CO2
    _O2
```

You've just skipped `Ar`.

One solution is as you have found: make a copy of the keys before iterating over them. Another solution is to build a new dictionary rather than modifying the existing one. I generally recommend this approach since it could make your code a fair bit cleaner in the process.

A third solution is to iterate the lists in reverse order so that the items you still have left to process don't move when you delete one; however, dictionary keys aren't guaranteed to be in any particular order. Although they are in the version of Python you're using, you shouldn't rely on that.

Comment: This is well explained, but following your logic, why does O2 not skipped also ? The first element to be process is N2 in this case. So why does only Ar is skipped ?

Comment: I've simplified it a bit because the item may actually go into the same slot in some circumstances, depending on the `dict` implementation. The point is, you can't reliably change dicts while iterating over them. It's possible with lists if you're careful, but dicts make no guarantees whatsoever about item order.

Comment: Essentially the data structure beneath `dict_keys` gets mangled by changing the `dict`, violating the contract between the user and the code. The problem with building a new `dict` is that here the `dict` is `self` which doesn't appear to be replaceable from within the object. I tried that first on a hunch and then fell back to replacing `dict` entries. The alternatives appear to either be horrible internals programming or an awful API.

Comment: In my use case, `dict` order isn't important otherwise I'd have used `collections.OrderedDict`. The main problem is that I intended to get a snapshot of the `dict` keys at the time I asked for them, not at the time Python felt like giving them to me. That's great for other use cases, just not this one.

Comment: Easy enough to freeze the snapshot, then, by converting it to a list (or a tuple as you do).

Comment: @arclight: `keys` is not intended to give you a snapshot.

Comment: @kindall: The view doesn't really behave like a list. There are no promises about how structurally modifying the dict will affect ongoing iteration operations, but in the current implementation, elements won't "slide" into previous positions when an entry is removed. Existing elements are only moved on a rehash (but rehashing can be hard to predict due to dummy entries).

Comment: Is there a `dict` variant that throws a warning or exception when a 'stale' instance of `dict_keys` is queried? I'd like to avoid this sort of silent failure in the future.

Comment: Sure, Python 2.x has such a variant. You explicitly can't delete keys from a dictionary while iterating over it.